# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false but ASP.NET_SessionId(cookie) is available

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-membership, claims-based-identity, katana

Everything was working but suddenly broke. Sorry for the poor description: will add any details if needed.

I am using a ASP.Net MVC SSO which uses Owin(OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider) and credentials verified on first call and cookies also created. But when client (ASP.net App)  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticate is still false and it is going back to SSO and user.Identity.IsAuthenticated which is coming from System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().

Hope gave enough information. please let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: You might want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question

Comment: Thanks, I mean I have no idea for this particular issue as it has many ways to implement and on many kinds of apps.  Please let me know if any more information is needed to understand the Question.